# pointer to pointer in C++

Tags: algorithm, pointers, data-structures

In this program why can't I use ***head=*head->next** in the change head line?

This is a geeksforgeek algorithm...

Or please suggest me some good tutorials to learn pointers

```
void deleteNode(struct node **head_ref, int key)
{
    // Store head node
    struct node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;

    // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted
    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key)
    {
        *head_ref = temp->next;  // Changed head
        free(temp);               // free old head
        return;
    }

    // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the
    // previous node as we need to change 'prev->next'
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // If key was not present in linked list
    if (temp == NULL) return;

    // Unlink the node from linked list
    prev->next = temp->next;

    free(temp);  // Free memory
}
```

Comment: I think `*head=*head->next` should work, did you try it? But temp serves other purposes as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*head_ref = *head_ref->next`.

But it is done using `temp` just to keep things clear. It would look at little vague if you compare using `temp->data` and then delete using `*head_ref`.

If you do want to use `*head_ref`, then you can change the code to make it look more clearer. like,

```
// If head node itself holds the key to be deleted
if (*head_ref != NULL && *head_ref->data == key)
{
    *head_ref = *head_ref->next;  // Changed head
    free(temp);                  // free old head
    return;
}
```

Comment: This won't work, but I figured out the solution (*head)->next. Without bracket is won't work